# MSI How to Add product name in Add/Remove program list of other user on same machine

Tags: windows-installer

I have a product msi, and it is installed as user level i.e. **AAUSERS** property is set to zero in **MSI** property table. This is a very old product and its already released. As its installed User specific, i can not see the product name in the Add/Remove program list of other users on same machine.

Is there any way like registry setting modification that i can do on one user which will make my product name to appear on Add/Remove program list of all users on the same machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do this. The whole point is that users have their own environment, and part of that is that they do not see other peoples Add/Remove entries or anything else (such as per user COM classes) that belong to other users. If another user has admin privilege there are tools that can find everything that's installed using APIs like MsiEnumProductsEx () and passing the other user's SID.

Comment: My product is already installed on customer machine. I understand that one user can not see other user specific data or registry. but is there any registry key which is responsible to show product name in "Add/Remove" program ?. which i can add it and which will make my product name appear in add/remove program. all users on the same machine are admin.